# preg_match whitespace problem

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need to write a regex but for some reason i cannot get the \s to find whitespace,
Im trying....

```
$name = "a ";

if( preg_match('^[a-z]+\s$', $name)){
  echo "match";
} else {
  echo "no match";
}
```

ive also tried

```
preg_match('^[a-z\s]+$');
```

and

```
preg_match('^[a-z]/\s/$');
```

Im just getting no match.
The full regex needs to allow 1 or more lowercase letters then a space then an uppercase letter followed by one or more lowercase, but....

```
preg_match('^[a-z]+\s[A-Z][a-z]+$');
```

isnt working as i'd expect it to going of the tutorials ive seen around the web (sitepoint etc...).

Anyone shed any light on it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to add [**delimiters**<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) to the expressions:

```
$name = "a ";

if( preg_match('/^[a-z]+\s$/', $name)){
//              ^          ^
//              └----------┴----- here: slash as delimiter
  echo "match";
} else {
  echo "no match";
}
```

Here I used a slash `/` but you are pretty much free in choosing a delimiter (ok, not that much: *any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character*).

---

Make sure you have error reporting set to include warnings, e.g. by adding `error_reporting(E_ALL)`. Then you would have seen this warning:

> Warning: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^' found in ... on line ...
>   no match

PHP treats the first character in the string as delimiter, so in your case the `^`.